# What are the Tools/Technologies available to develop a cross platform web Apps Interface?

Tags: web-applications, mobile-website

I want to develop a location-based social network to be accessed from PCs and Mobile Devices.
For Mobile Devices I want to deliver a native-looking app to access the Network.For WP7,iOS and Android. But I don't want to write truly native apps so that I dont have to re-write the App for each Platformm, and second because the App is all web based.
So I better be using web technologies. The question is, for these Client Apps, what are the Frameworks or Libraries available to use?

Comment: PhoneGap and Titanium AppCelerator are two Pop Favorite choices...  Q: How are your Javascript/HTML5/CSS coding skills?

Comment: Basic SkillsI would say, but good in Java and C++ otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for PhoneGap in your case. Write once deliver everywhere.It also let you easily use other libraries and Framworks like Secha.

Other options are Titanium AppAccelerator, MoSync.